# Visual Studio Code Debugger - ask for CLI arguments

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I use debugger for Python in Visual Studio Code. It works great, but in many cases I want to debug scripts which use different CLI arguments. It's very cumbersome to create an entry in `lauch.json` for each CLI argument group I want to debug.

I'm looking for a way for VSC to ask for CLI arguments which will be passed to the script hen debugger starts. I would be even better is there would be some history of previous arguments.

PS. I know you can attach the debugger and run it via the command line, but I hope there is a clean solution :)

Answer (score 0):

About your question:

> I'm looking for a way for VSC to ask for CLI arguments which will be passed to the script hen debugger starts.

I'm sorry to tell you that the request can't be met. For now, there're two ways to debug showed in [python-debug](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging):

1. Add configurations in the launch.json, then press Run->Start Debugging, which will create a debug process automatically that provided by the python extension. During this debug process, all debug configurations depend on the content in launch.json:
   [image]
2. Command line debugging. The debugger command line syntax you can refer to [commandline-debug](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_command-line-debugging). Compared to changing configurations in launch.json every time, this is more convenient.

More information about debug in VS Code, please refer to [Debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging)